# How can I get the Oracle TNSListener to start after changing my host name?

Tags: oracle

When running

```
lsnrctl status
```

I can see that it is using the old host name, but I don't know where it is pulling that value from.

My Oracle installation is 11.2.0 on Windows7 x64, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `lsnrctl status`, one of the things that it tells you is the location of the Listener Parameter File (the listener.ora file)

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 06-JUN-2012 13:12:22

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                06-JUN-2012 09:33:58
Uptime                    0 days 3 hr. 38 min. 24 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\jcave8560w\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "jcave11gR2XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "jcave11gr2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "jcave11gr2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "jcave11gr2", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

If you open that file, there will probably be an entry like this

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

where the host is specified.  Change the host there and restart the listener.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm... I also had to change a file named tsanames.ora but it was in the same dir so it was easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your listener has the domain name included you may need to alter the oracle init parameters `SERVICE_NAME` and `DB_DOMAIN` depending on what is changing in the host name/ service name.

```
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/yourserver/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=yourserver.yyy.zzz.edu)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "yoursid.yyy.zzz.edu" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "yoursid", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "yoursidXDB.yyy.zzz.edu" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "yoursid", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```